# Add a portion of a unit circle

Tags: graphics

Consider:

```
a = {9, -5};
u = a/Norm[a];

Graphics[{
  Blue, Arrow[{{0, 0}, a}],
  Red, Arrow[{{0, 0}, u}],
  Text[Style["<9, -5>", Blue, Background -> White], {9, -5.4}],
  Text[Style[
    "<\!\(\*FractionBox[\(9\), SqrtBox[\(106\)]]\), \
-\!\(\*FractionBox[\(5\), SqrtBox[\(106\)]]\)>", Red, 
    Background -> White], {1.5, -1.5}]
  },
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-6, 0}},
 GridLines -> {Range[1, 10], Range[-6, -1]}]
```

Which gives this image:

[image]

Now, I'd like to add a piece of a unit circle (in Red), which goes from the point (1,0) to the point (0,-1).

Suggestions?

Comment: `Circle[]` can take a third argument for producing arcs of circles; you might want to look at that. Also, `a/Norm[a]` is more compactly done as `Normalize[a]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The edit is the additional graphic. You can dress up the coloring and thickness yourself, here's the modification (the new first graphic entry):

```
a = {9, -5};
u = a/Norm[a];

Graphics[{
Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {0, -Pi/2}], 
Blue, Arrow[{{0, 0}, a}], 
Red, Arrow[{{0, 0}, u}], 
Text[Style["<9, -5>", Blue, Background -> White], {9, -5.4}], 
Text[Style[
"<\!\(\*FractionBox[\(9\), SqrtBox[\(106\)]]\), \
-\!\(\*FractionBox[\(5\), SqrtBox[\(106\)]]\)>", Red, 
Background -> White], {1.5, -1.5}]}, Axes -> True, 
AxesLabel -> {x, y}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-6, 0}}, 
GridLines -> {Range[1, 10], Range[-6, -1]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Now I am searching for a way to add an arrow to the end of the circle. Gonna read [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705243/how-can-i-make-a-directed-arc-of-a-circle-or-a-directed-curve/5706674#5706674](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705243/how-can-i-make-a-directed-arc-of-a-circle-or-a-directed-curve/5706674#5706674).

Comment: @David Regarding an arrowhead, for lack of anything better, add the graphic line below the circle segment graphic line, `Arrow[{{.001, -1}, {0, -1}}, -.2]`. Seems like a bit of a cheat, but it works. It'll give you a red arrowhead at the end of that circle segment, and only the arrowhead will show.You might tweak those parameters a bit, but set that way on your graph, it looks fine to me. Basically an arrow with no tail.

Comment: Right now, the simplest thing I have found for students that are beginners in Mathematica is: Red, Arrow[Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, -Pi/2, -Pi/100}]],

Comment: I actually saw that. Looks good too.